# Получить прогресс выполнение хранимой процедуры

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

Допустим, где-то на SQL Server есть хранимка, которая запуская без параметров.

Внутри себя извлекает ID по некоторому условию и лопатит их курсором.

Есть ли способы на стороне C# получить прогресс выполнения? Понятное дело, что сам SQL Server не может расчитать время выполнения. Но если в процедуру добавить какие-нибудь `print`, то можно ли их как нибудь получать в коде во время выполнения самой процедуры?

Какие могут быть альтернативы?

Comment: в процедуре пишите в какую нибудь таблицу текущее состояние. И читаете эту таблицу с уровнем изоляции транзакции read uncommited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел событие [InfoMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage(v=vs.110).aspx) с помощью которого можно получать от процедуры сообщения.

Т.е я могу в процедуре вызывать Print, а на стороне клиента эти Print выводить.

Comment: Проверьте, насколько быстро этот print возвращается. Если через студию делается print в начале процедуры, то он возвращается только после ее выполнения, или, если процедура очень долгая, через несколько минут после того, как реально должен был появиться. Для мгновенного появления сообщения в студии я использую следующую конструкцию: "raiserror(@text, 0, 0, 0) with nowait;" - в @text собственно содержимое. Такое сообщение выводится сразу.